# Calculation of Poisson distribution in C

Tags: c, distribution, poisson

I need a C function to calculate Poisson distribution for values of k up to 720. I need a highly efficient solution.

Comment: This is not RentACoder, and lack of planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on our part. You're supposed to at least put in a minimal effort (and tell us what it was) rather than just make demands.

Answer (score 7):

give a to try [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/): [`gsl_ran_poisson_pdf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Poisson-Distribution.html)

Answer (score 4):

Poisson Random Generator

```
int poissonRandom(double expectedValue) {
  int n = 0; //counter of iteration
  double limit; 
  double x;  //pseudo random number
  limit = exp(-expectedValue);
  x = rand() / INT_MAX; 
  while (x > limit) {
    n++;
    x *= rand() / INT_MAX;
  }
  return n;
}
```

I guess I'm pretty late for your urgent demand.

Comment: This also discussed with others at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Generating_Poisson-distributed_random_variables

Comment: Unless you redefine `INT_MAX`, which one should never do, to a floating-point value, `rand() / INT_MAX` is always zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate it yourself instead of using a library
You can calculate it using the formula.. e^k*e^(-lambda)/k!
you can use log(n!) = log(n)+log(n-1!) and  dynamic programming

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is far too late for the original request, but I think some of the answers miss the point - I don't think he wants to generate random numbers from a distribution, but wants the distribution itself. Here is a function to do this
avoiding the calculation of factorials which can become large.

```
double poisson( int k, double mean ) { 
  double p = std::exp(-mean);
  double f = 1;
  for ( int i=0 ; i<k ; i++ ) f *= mean/(i+1);     
  return p*f;
}
```