# How do I generate normally distributed positive integers in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, statistics

I am writing a program in C that requires generating a normal distribution of positive integers with mean less than 1.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You can generate random numbers using `rand()`.

Comment: If the mean of a set of positive integers is to be less than 1, then most of the values must be 0.

Comment: how can something that is restricted to positive integers have a normal distribution?

Comment: @JensGustedt Or mean less than 1, for that matter.

Comment: It can be, if we have a large enough sample (in my case, it's 2^20), by CLT, we can approximate it to be a near-normal distribution.

Comment: Currently what I have to do is generate this set of random positive integers using Matlab, and then call for that set when I run my program. But this method isn't very efficient. Also for multiple runs, I have to keep on running the Matlab code each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize data that is already normally distributed, for example take data for average length of human beings (180 centimeter) and scale every number by a factor so that the mean becomes less than 1 e.g. multiply every length by 1/180.

Comment: I need positive integers as random numbers. So scaling won't work. For example, 175/180 won't be an integer.

Comment: Can you use the central limit theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem and a binomial distribution large enough, will aprox,. normal?

Comment: I think I should be able to use it.

Comment: I tested it in Excel and it has functions to do it: `=INT(NORMINV(RAND(); 0,5; 0,4))` will generate random integers with mean 0,5 and s.d. 0,4. If we can do it in Excel we can learn the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Poisson random number generator function in C, which takes the mean as input. I used a combination of rand() followed by exponentiation to get the distribution, which is the normal way to do this, as in [Calculation of Poisson distribution in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057621/calculation-of-poisson-distribution-in-c).
Since I generate 2^14 random numbers, by Central Limit theorem, their distribution will tend to a normal distribution, with the same mean and variance.